# Preservation of completeness under isomorphisms between Boolean algebras

Tags: boolean-algebra

> A Boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}:=(B,\leq,\lor,\land,^c,0,1)$ is said to be complete if every non-empty subset of $B$ has a greatest lower bound (g.l.b). Prove that a Boolean algebra that is isomorphic to a complete Boolean algebra is complete.

Let us start with a *complete* Boolean algebra, $\mathcal{B}:=(B,\leq,\lor,\land,^c,0,1)$ which is isomorphic to $\mathcal{B'}:=(B',\leq,\lor,\land,^c,0,1)$. Let $h:B\to B'$ be an isomorphism between the two.

For a non-empty subset $X' \subseteq B'$, $\exists X\in B$ such that $h(X)=B$. **Is this correct, or does it need more justification?** I think this is fine because: for every element $x' \in X'$ we have $x \in X$ such that $h(x) = x'$ since $h$ is an isomorphism. We can construct $X$ such that $h(X)= X'$ by $X = \{x\in B:x = h^{-1}(x') \forall x' \in X'\}$.

Since $\mathcal{B}$ is complete, we know that $X$ has a g.l.b, say $x_g \in X$. This means that for all $x\in X$, $x_g\leq x$. Since isomorphisms between Boolean algebras preserve partial orders, it follows that $h(x_g)\leq h(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Since $X'=\{x'\in B':x'=h(x) \forall x\in X\}$, $h(x_g)$ is in fact the g.l.b of $X'$. **Is this fine?**

This works for all $X'\subseteq B'$, hence $\mathcal{B}'$ is complete.

*I'm new to proof-writing, and I tend to make mistakes or leave out things that need to be stated in order to complete a proof. Hence, it would be helpful if someone could just go through this and let me know if the aforementioned steps are complete, or some gaps need to be filled in?* I'd be happy to know about ways to make this proof more rigorous.

Comment: I think you mean: for $X'\subseteq B',\,\exists X\subseteq B:\,h(X')=X$. Which is what you seem doing, and it's fine.

Comment: I think you mean $h(X) = X'$? In my construction, at least, $h^{-1}(X') = X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’ve done is correct, but the fact that $h(x_g)\le x'$ for each $x'\in X'$ isn’t enough to show that $h(x_g)=\bigwedge X'$: it shows that $h(x_g)$ is **a** lower bound for $X'$, but it doesn’t show that $h(x_g)$ is the **greatest** lower bound for $X'$. For that you need to verify that $b'\le h(x_g)$ whenever $b'$ is a lower bound for $X'$. But that’s straightforward: if $b'\le x'$ for each $x'\in X'$, then $h^{-1}(b')\le h^{-1}(x')$ for each $x'\in X'$, so $h^{-1}(b')\le x_g$, and therefore $b'\le h(x_g)$.